# Dados de formulário não são enviados para o banco de dados

Tags: php, pdo

Estou com um problema para enviar dados de um formulário para o banco de dados o script roda sem apontar um erro aparentemente mas não insere os dados alguém saberia o problema segue o código :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

<title>Olá, mundo!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=tarefas;host=localhost", "root", "admin");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "ERRO: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>
<br/>
<form action="tarefas.php" method="POST">
Nome: <input name="nome" type="text"/> <br/>
Descricao: <input name="descricao" type="text"/><br/>
<input value="Enviar" type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
$qt_por_pagina = 5;

$total = 0;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM tarefas";
$sql = $pdo->query($sql);
$sql = $sql->fetch();
$total = $sql['c'];
$paginas = $total / $qt_por_pagina;

$pg = '1';
if (isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])) {
$pg = addslashes($_GET['p']);
}

$p = ($pg - 1) * $qt_por_pagina;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tarefas LIMIT $p, $qt_por_pagina";
$sql = $pdo->query($sql);

if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $item) {
    echo "Id:".$item['id'] ."<br/>Nome:".$item['nome']. "<br/>Descricao: " . $item['descricao'] . "<br/>";
}
}

echo "<hr/>";

for ($q=0; $q < $paginas; $q++) {
echo '<a href="./?p='.($q+1).'">[ '.($q+1).' ]</a>';
}

?>
<!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
<!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="bootstrap/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/popper/popper.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



<?php 
try {
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=tarefas;host=localhost", "root", "admin");
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "ERRO: " . $e->getMessage();
}

//definindo posts
$nome = isset($_POST['nome'])?$_POST['nome']:null;
$descricao = isset($_POST['descricao'])?$_POST['descricao']:null;

if(empty($nome)){
  echo "Colocar o nome!";
}
if(empty($descricao)){
  echo "Colocar descricao!";
} else {
  $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO tarefas SET nome='".$nome."', descricao='".$descricao."'");

  echo "Tarefa enviada<br/><a href=\"index.php\">Voltar</a>";
  exit();
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Para formatar o código, selecione o mesmo e aperte o atalho `CTRL+K` ou clique no botão `{}` no editor. Caso precise de ajuda, acesse a [help].

Comment: valeu tava com problemas para destacar o código é que estou pelo celular

Comment: Coloque o HTML do seu formulário na pergunta para facilitar o entendimento do problema. Apenas com esse trecho de código apresentado não dá para identificar o erro.

Comment: atualizei o post

Comment: No *insert* não se usa  `SET`, mas sim `VALUES`: `insert into [table] values ([values])`

Answer (score 1):

consegui resolver, o problema era que na coluna id eu esqueci de definir como auto increment mas atualizei o script para não correr o risco de tomar sql injection de qualquer forma se alguém quiser tá aí funcionando :

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=tarefas;host=localhost", "root", "admin");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "ERRO: " . $e->getMessage();
}
//definindo posts

$nome = isset($_POST['nome'])?$_POST['nome']:null;
$descricao = isset($_POST['descricao'])?$_POST['descricao']:null;

if(empty($nome))
{
echo "Colocar o nome!";
}
if(empty($descricao))
{
echo "Colocar descricao!";
}else{

$sql = "INSERT INTO tarefas(nome, descricao) VALUES(:nome, :descricao) ";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare( $sql ); 

$stmt->bindParam( ':nome', $nome ); 

$stmt->bindParam( ':descricao', $descricao );

$result = $stmt->execute();   

if ( ! $result ) 
{ 
var_dump( $stmt->errorInfo() ); 

exit(); 

}   
echo $stmt->rowCount() . "linhas inseridas";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
  $execute=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tarefas (nome,descricao) VALUES ('$nome','$descricao')");
  $execute->execute();
  echo "Tarefa enviada<br/><a href=\"index.php\">Voltar</a>";
  exit();
```

Comment: eu já tinha tentado assim antes e não obtive sucesso continuo a mesma coisa 

Answer (score 0):

Altere para o seguinte:

```
else 
{
   $sql = ("INSERT INTO tarefas (nome, descricao) VALUES ('$nome', 
  '$descricao');") or die (mysql_error());
   $result = mysql_query($sql); // Executa o insert

   echo "Tarefa enviada<br/><a href=\"index.php\">Voltar</a>";
   exit();
}
```

Caso não dê certo, faça testes com suas variaveis e conexão com o banco.